# How can I programmatically configure the BIOS on windows machine to automatically boot when power is restored?

Tags: boot, bios

I'm developing a data acquisition program that which is used in locations that experience occasional and unpredictable power outages. Since the end-users are not always on site to reboot their computers manually I'm looking for a way to programmatically change the BIOS settings of their machine's to automatically re-boot them.

Specifically, I want set the "**Restore from AC power loss**" option to "**always on**". Can this be scripted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are the answer to your question is going to be manufacturer-specific.

For example, Dell computers come with a management suite "[Dell OpenManage](http://www.delltechcenter.com/page/Dell+Systems+Management#fbid=ob0vy43HokQ)" which allows administrators to remotely administer Dell machines, and set options such as "Restore from AC power loss", including through scripting options.  HP, IBM, and other enterprise systems vendors have comparable tools.

Unfortunately BIOS Setup options do not adhere to an industry-standard spec, so there is no one-size fits all answer to your question.